# Wifi won't turn on after using xender, Unless phone restarts

Tags: cyanogenmod, wi-fi, 6.0-marshmallow

```
Device: Samsung Galaxy Grand Duos (gt-19082)
Current ROM: CM13.O Unofficial port.
```

After using a Wifi file transfer app like Xender(turns my hotspot ON)
when I try to turn ON wifi, the toggle goes gray(unresponsive). The problem persists unless I restart the phone.

I am experiencing this problem from way back while I had CM12. Now I have upgraded to Marshmallow.

Comment: The situation persists any app that use hotspot for transfering.
Ok, I will report it into Cyanogenmod. Thanks :)

Comment: Let me see whether it solves my problem. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last the problem got solved.

I had to backup all my data, do a hard reset.

I flashed with a new version of Cyanogenmod, and then with nano Gapps.
And a full reset after flashing it with Gapps.

After reboot, Reinstalled all apps from backup, and the problem was solved, wifi works well now.